# Call to setState in onDragStart causes DOM node to be deleted?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, jsx, styled-components

I use a list of styled components for displaying some info. I want this info to be sortable. The real problem I'm trying to solve is actually way more complex than what I'm demonstrating here. So any odd design choices are very specific to what I'm trying to do. I'm just mentioning it because the code I'm showing will be very simplified but it will also show some of these at first glance odd design choices.

I've read this article: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/react-drag-and-drop-7411d14894b9

Temitope Emmanuel (the author) did what I'm trying to achieve but with just a plain div. I don't know whether he tested all of what he proposes in his article.

Off to some code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default class SomeList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // in real problem all of these are props
    // pulled off the state of a parent
    this.state = {
      dragging: false,
      listOfChildrenInOrder: ['1', '2', '3'],
      itemComponent: styled.div`
        border: 1px solid black;
      `,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      dragging,
      listOfChildrenInOrder,
      itemComponent: ItemComponent,
    } = this.state;
    const {
      children,
    } = this.props;

    const Container = styled.div`
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: max-content;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(${listOfChildrenInOrder.length}, max-content) 1fr;
    `;

    const Droppable = styled.div`
      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      }
    `;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Fragment>
          {listOfChildrenInOrder.map(((cid, i) => (
            <ItemComponent
              draggable
              key={`ic-${cid}`}
              style={{
                gridArea: `1 / ${i + 1} / span 1 / span 1`,
              }}
              onDragStart={(e) => {
                this.setState({ dragging: true });
                e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', `${cid}`);
              }}
              onDragEnd={() => {
                this.setState({ dragging: false });
                // doesn't even fire anymore
              }}
            >
              {children.find(c => c.key === cid)}
            </ItemComponent>
          )))}
        </Fragment>
        <Fragment>
          {dragging && listOfChildrenInOrder.map(((cid, i) => (
            <Droppable
              key={`d-${cid}`}
              style={{
                gridArea: `1 / ${i + 1} / span 1 / span 1`,
              }}
              onDragOver={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
              }}
              onDrop={() => {
                // do whatever (out of scope), doesn't get called anyway
              }}
            >
              {children.find(c => c.key === cid)}
            </Droppable>
          )))}
        </Fragment>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the reconciler (Fiber) to update the DOM node without straight out replacing it in the middle of a drag operation. I'm using these things to act as highlighters. The real Problem I'm trying to solve actually makes a difference on where exactly stuff gets dropped, so the grid in the real problem is finer, with more droppables and one item component spaning multiple grid columns. Like I said: odd choices, but not without purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know now what was causing this whole operation to fail. The reason was dynamically creating new styled components in the render loop. Never do that. Just another rule of thumb learned.